# Building a dist folder for Vue JS project

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create distribution folder for different environments (sit, uat, production). For this I have started using .env files for my Vue js project. Whem I am doing yarn sit or npm run sit. My dis. folder in linux box is not created properly. But in my windows machine it is working properly.
In my package.json, I have different scripts for different environment.

```
"sit": "vue-cli-service --mode sit build",
```

In my windows machine, this is how the dist folder created.
[image: winddows machine dist folder]

[image: linux box dist folder]

I am not sure what is the issue. In my dev depe, I have "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15"

Comment: What do you mean by not created properly?  What is the error?

Comment: If you see the image, in the windows machine,all the folders are created like js,css,fonts,image. But in linxu, js is just directly in the dist folder and I dont have any img,css folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out the issue.
First of all, we can use as many `.env`-file as per our requirement. If you want to use and create a production-like `dist`-folder, you have to specify the `NODE_ENV` on top of your file.
For example, If I want my `uat` environment package the same as production (which should be the same as production as we have to deploy on a server), just add `NODE_ENV=production` before your property file.

In your `package.json`, you have to add

```
"prod": "vue-cli-service --mode prod build"
```

At the time of creating the package, you can do `npm run prod` or `yarn prod`, whichever you use.

The issue which was happening was that for some other requirement, we were setting the `NODE_ENV` to some other value.
If `NODE_ENV` is already set to some junk value, the package build was not happening correctly. But when I unset the environment variable, all was good.

Right now, I have multiple `.env`-files as per the environment and I can create the `dist`-folder similar to production for deployment in the respective environment.

Answer (score 2):

When you build using `vue-cli-service` your `mode` does indeed trigger including the appropriate `.env` file you've set up. However, regardless of the number of environments you have, the `vue-cli-service` builds only two different types of distributions by default depending upon the `--mode` switch:

1. **production**, which is the default `mode` (or you can specify it with `--mode production`; or
2. **non-production**, which in your case, is `--mode sit` and `--mode uat`.

By default, when you build for `production` your app is bundled up and you get the `js` directory, `css` etc depending upon your setup. For any other `mode` you specify, it builds a non-production distribution which does not have the app bundled, so you will not see the `js` folder for example. This is by default.

Now, in your case, what you're saying is that this performs differently depending upon the OS. I don't know your exact setup, but you either have an environment difference on the two machines, are running different commands, or there is a defect in `vue-cli-service` which you may need to raise an issue for. Double / triple check your environments and the commands you're running.

Just as an aside, if you're trying to build for different environments, you may want to add the `dest` switch to your build command so you can build to a different directory - something like:

```
"sit": "vue-cli-service build --mode sit --dest ./dist/sit",
"uat": "vue-cli-service build --mode uat --dest ./dist/uat",
"production": "vue-cli-service build --mode production --dest ./dist/production"
```